# Sunspot-Solr does not work correctly when a single letter is within the Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I have a query `"Winning X Factor"` in my Sunspot Solr rails app.

This returns no results. However, when querying `"Winning Factor"`, `"Winning"`, or `"Factor"` I get the result I'm looking for.

When the X is in there it destroys the search, and no results are returned.

On my local, I updated my Dismax settings to look like so :

```
<str name="mm">2&lt;-1 5&lt;70%</str>
```

Then the search results return as expected. Basically, this applies fuzziness acceptability to singleton clauses.

However, if I do this remotely, it doesn't work the same way.

Per making a change, I reload the core ( and/or also restarted all of sunspot ), and reindex my object. Then perform my query..

Does anyone know any alternatives for allowing singletons to simply be ignored?

Comment: whats the field type for the field ? and the definition ?

Comment: As in, what's written in my model?

Comment: Can you share the field description in the schema.xml file?